# How to use getContactGroups() to list all groups the contacts belongs to

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-contacts

I've the following script which grabs my contacts:

```
function onOpen()
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push( {name: "Read Contacts", functionName: "readContacts"} );
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Contacts", menuEntries);
};


function readContacts() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Contacts");

  sheet.clear();
  var group  = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Apptivo Contacts');
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(group);
//var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
  var ContactArray  = new Array();
  var ContactArrays = [];

  ContactArray = [];
  ContactArray.push("");
  ContactArray.push("FullName");
  ContactArray.push("Email");
  ContactArray.push("Mobile");
  ContactArray.push("HomePhone");
  ContactArray.push("WorkPhone");
  ContactArray.push("Company");
  ContactArray.push("Job Title");
  ContactArray.push("Notes");  
  ContactArray.push("HomeAddress");
  ContactArray.push("WorkAddress");
  ContactArray.push("URL");
  ContactArray.push("Group0");
  ContactArray.push("Group1");
  ContactArray.push("Group2");

  ContactArrays.push(ContactArray);

  for (var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++)
  {
    ContactArray = [];
    ContactArray.push("");
    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getFullName());
    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getPrimaryEmail());
    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getMobilePhone());
    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getHomePhone());
    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getWorkPhone());

    try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getCompanies()[0].getCompanyName());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}
    try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getCompanies()[0].getJobTitle());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getNotes());
    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getHomeAddress());
    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getWorkAddress());

    try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getUrls()[0].getAddress());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

    ///Replace this section with new code
    try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getContactGroups()[0].getName());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}
    try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getContactGroups()[1].getName());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}
    try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getContactGroups()[2].getName());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}


    ContactArrays.push(ContactArray);
  }

sheet.getRange(1,1,ContactArrays.length,ContactArrays[0].length).setValues(ContactArrays);
};
```

The script works perfectly fine but I'd like to modify it to list all the groups in one column instead of the first three groups in three columns.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced that section with the following code and everything seems fine.. If there is a better way please advise.

```
var ListofGroups = "";    
for ( var g=0;g<contacts[i].getContactGroups().length;g++)
{
  ListofGroups += contacts[i].getContactGroups()[g].getName();
  ListofGroups += " | ";
}
try{ContactArray.push(ListofGroups);}
  catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}
```